# Phpmyadmin and replication

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have mysql-5.1.73 master database and slaves. I have database asterisk and table for replicate `mytable`

Master settings:

```
server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 1
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog-do-db            = asterisk
slave-compressed        = 1
```

First type of slaves mysql-5.1.73 settings:

```
replicate-do-db         = asterisk
replicate-do-table      = asterisk.mytable
```

Second type of slave mariadb-5.5.56 settings:

```
server-id = 1000
log_bin = /var/log/mariadb/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days = 2
max_binlog_size  = 100M
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-slave-updates
binlog_do_db = voip
replicate-rewrite-db=asterisk->voip
replicate-do-table = voip.mytable
```

At second slave type I rename database from `asterisk` to `voip`. And that slave become master for others (slaves type 3 :).

If I add new data to master (server-id 1) from mysql command line - data replicates to all slaves. It's ok.
But if I add new data to master (server-id 1) from phpmyadmin - data replicates only to slaves type 1 and doesn't replicate to slave type 2.
phpmyadmin version 4.0.10.20 (latest at 4.0 branch)

Is it phpmyadmin issue? Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I think that [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) is a much better match for you problem. Stack overflow is for programming related questions where server fault focuses on system administration.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

```
replicate-do-table = asterisk.mytable
replicate-rewrite-db = asterisk->voip
```

This is your telephone system?  Suggest you not play around in DB `asterisk`, but create another database.